# Proving that floor(n/2)=n/2 if n is an even integer and floor(n/2)=(n-1)/2 if n is an odd integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

How would one go about proving the following. Any ideas as to where to start?

For any integer n, the floor of n/2 equals n/2 if n is even and (n-1)/2 if n is odd.

Summarize:

```
[n/2] = n/2 if n = even

[n/2] = (n-1)/2 if n = odd
```

Working through it, I try to initially set n = 2n for the even case but am stuck on how to show its a floor...

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set $n=2m$ for even numbers, where $m$ is an integer.  Then $\frac n2=m$ and the floor of an integer is itself.  The odd case is similar.

Comment: for the odd case, if i set n = 6m+1, which is always odd and plug in for simplification...will that be sufficient for proof? I got 3m at the end

Comment: @user1234440 For generality set $n=2m+1$ or $n=2m-1$.

Comment: @user1234440:  For the odd case, if $n=2m+1$, with $m$ integral, what is $\frac n2$ in terms of $m$

Comment: for the odd case, its n-1/2 in terms of m

Comment: @user1234440: no, $\frac n2=m+\frac 12$ and the floor of that is $m$