# Discrete Mathematics functions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, discrete-mathematics, integers

Prove that if $n$ is an integer,then

> $[n/2]=n/2$    if $n$ is even
>
> $[n/2]=(n-1)/2$    if $n$ is odd

I want to know the  methodical answer for this question, I have reached out here to the same [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215909/proving-that-floorn-2-n-2-if-n-is-an-even-integer-and-floorn-2-n-1-2-if-n?newreg=9988d413cf974f3aa31e699c466a17e5) unfortunately he hasn't added the full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\;\lfloor x\rfloor\;$ is "the integer part of $\;x\,$" or "floor function", which means: the greatest integer number *which is still less than or equal* $\;x\;$ . So if $\;n=2k\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;$ is even , then

$$\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor=\lfloor k\rfloor=k=\frac{2k}2=\frac n2$$

Now you try to figure out the other one, taking into account that if $\;n\;$ is odd, then $\;n=2k+1\;$ .

Comment: Thank you so much for the methodical explanation.I managed to get the other answer.I should probably go through the chapter again

Answer (score 0):

Let' assume n is a non-negative integer: $n \in \mathbb{N}$

If n is even, by definition, $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}, n=2k$. Then compare $[n/2]$ and $n/2$ ... Hint: is $n/2$ an integer ?

If n is odd, by definition, $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}, n=2k+1$ then compare $[n/2]$ and $n/2$... Same hint !

Comment: Thank you so much for your help,I was managed to get the answer .I should probably go through the chapter again.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is even, then $n=2k$ and so $n/2=2k/2 = k$.
If $n$ is odd, then $n=2k+1$ and so $(n-1)/2 = 2k/2=k$ with $k=(n-1)/2$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great help in a short time.I was managed to get the answer so easily thanks to you.I should probably go through the chapter again.

Answer (score 0):

By the division theorem,

$$n=2m+r$$ where $m$ is the quotient, i.e. $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$, and $r$ the remainder, $0$ for even, $1$ for odd.

We can rewrite

- even $n\to\left\lfloor \dfrac n2\right\rfloor=\dfrac{n-0}2$
- odd $n\to\left\lfloor \dfrac n2\right\rfloor=\dfrac{n-1}2.$

More generally, for any divisor $d$ we have

$$\left\lfloor \dfrac nd\right\rfloor=\dfrac{n-(n\bmod d)}d.$$

---

Other method:

$$\left\lfloor\frac{(2k)}2\right\rfloor=k=\frac{(2k)}2$$

$$\left\lfloor\frac{(2k+1)}2\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor k+\frac12\right\rfloor=k=\frac{(2k+1)-1}2$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the brief methodical explanation.I have to go through the whole chapter again,Thank you once again